# What is the syntax for making a regexmatch query case insenitive when also pinging off another cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm working on creating a 'search function' for a google sheet.  The idea is that someone can type in keywords they want and don't want and a list will auto-populate below.  I'm trying to figure out how to make it case insensitive.  I've seen that you can do (?i) but as I'm pinging off a cell, I'm not sure how to format that in (the things I've tried have lead to errors).

Posted my whole query below, but the bolded section is where I'm directly taking the search terms.

=iferror(query(filter('Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!A2:W3247,if(ISBLANK('Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247), "randomnessisathing",'Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247)='Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247, **if(regexmatch('Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247, (if(ISBLANK(D3),"randomnessisathing",D3))), 1, 0)=0, (if(regexmatch('Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247, D2)**, 'Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247, 0)='Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H3247)),"select Col1"),"No results found.")

Thanks so much!
Anna

Edit: Attaching a sample.  Unfortunately, I can't force everything to be lower or Title case because I'm dealing with Titles that need to be exported as is elsewhere.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AZs4tvrTvhvo9HqBJWt2_HwHJJLW6TidnHOBI58pDwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if possible, it helps to provide a sample sheet, with sample data, for people to more clearly understand what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried.  I don't know if you've already tried to force everything to lower case prior to doing the comparison of your keywords against your data values.

Comment: Just did!  @kirkg13

Comment: Why not use `"(?i)" & ..."`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!  I just didn't know the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a formula that works for you.
Try this query:

```
=QUERY('Archive Catalog-DO NOT TOUCH'!H2:H,
   "SELECT H WHERE UPPER(H) CONTAINS '"& UPPER(D2) &"' 
           AND NOT UPPER(H) CONTAINS '"& UPPER(D3) &"' ",0)
```

This forces both sides of the comparison to uppercase, before doing the comparison.  Then the query selects the records that contains the "includes" keyword, and doesn't contain the "excludes" keyword.

Note that if this works for you, but you want to enable multiple "includes" keywords, you can enter each keyword/string in its own cell, and use mutiple comparisons in the query to match all of the keywords.